# synchronous ajax requests not handled synchronous

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a loop that sends multiple ajax request.

When all these are completed I want to reload my page.

```
$.each(uuids, function (i, e) {
    console.log("Sending request for: " + e)
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            _rnd: new Date().getTime()
        },
        url: addToGroupUrl + '?label=' + encodeURIComponent($("#changeGroupSelect").val()) + '&labelDisplay=' + encodeURIComponent($("#changeGroupSelect option:selected").text()) + '&uuid=' + e,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: 'false',
    });
});

location.reload()
```

Now I have issues where not all requests are made. The loop creates all requests, but as soon as location.reload() is done the server stop receiving requests.

It seems like `async: 'false'` only prepare requests, but that they are handled async.

How am I suppose to think here? I want to reload my page when all requests has been sent.

Comment: have a look at premises of jquery (when...done and that sort of stuff)

Comment: `'false'` !== `false`

Comment: And why don't you send only one request containing all uuids as parameter and handle logic server side??? And of course using async request

Comment: I'm not developing the server side.

Comment: @LordVermillion So that makes sense :)

Answer (score 5):

Firstly the `async` property accepts a boolean value, not a string, so it should be `async: false`.

Secondly, and far more importantly, ***NEVER EVER use `async: false`***. It is *horrendous* for the user experience because it completely blocks the UI from being updated and makes the browser look like it crashed.

Instead, make all requests asynchronously and place all their promises in an array which you can `apply` to `$.when` before executing your required code when they all complete. Try this:

```
var requests = [];
var label = $("#changeGroupSelect").val();
var labelDisplay = $("#changeGroupSelect option:selected").text();
$.each(uuids, function (i, e) {
    requests.push($.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            _rnd: new Date().getTime(),
            label: label,
            labelDisplay: labelDisplay,
            uuid: e
        },
        url: addToGroupUrl,
        dataType: 'json'
    }));
});

$.when.apply(this, requests).done(function() {
    window.location.reload()
});
```

Note that if you provide the URL parameters to the `data` property they will automatically be encoded for you. Also, because the values of the inputs do not change between requests, you can grab them outside of the loop to stop the DOM being needlessly queried in each iteration.

Comment: All requests got to the server now, however the $.when.apply function is never called.

Comment: Check the network tab to make sure they all complete successfully with `200 OK` responses. You may wish to also include a `fail()` handler as well.

Comment: In the network tab i can see that all requests has been made, and all have a status '200'.

Comment: All this code is part of a function, should the $.when be outside of the function?

Comment: It doesn't really matter where you call it from, so long as the `requests` array is in scope and populated with deferred objects.

Answer (score 1):

async parameter of ajax, excepts a boolean value, try it like this:

`async: false`

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings